# LLVM: moving generated code around in a distributed/concurrent system

Tags: concurrency, code-generation, llvm, move

I'm using the LLVM C++ API mostly as a code generator for a scripting language that is parsed and evaluated (generating code, compiling, and executing it) at runtime. Currently I'm investigating future use cases in the context of a distributed/concurrent system and wonder if and how these use cases could be implemented. Maybe you can share your thoughts:

1. Is there a way to generate LLVM code on one node in a distributed
   system, serialize it to some wire format, send it to another node,
   compile or recompile it there and then execute it? I'm already stuck
   finding methods to serialize a module/function.
2. Are there ways to enable multi-threaded code
   generation/compilation within the same LLVMContext, i.e., a pool of
   threads shares a LLVMContext and generate/execute code within this
   context simultaneously. What I found out so far is that there should
   be a LLVMContext for each thread in this case. However, I can I then
   share a module between the different contexts and relating to 1),
   how could I move generated code from one module to the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely use LLVM bitcode format to forward the code from one node to another. See include/llvm/Bitcode/ReaderWriter.h and around for more info. You can also check the sources of LLVM tools to see how the bitcode is serialized and deserialized. You might find http://llvm.org/docs/BitCodeFormat.html useful.